# php way to get date 15 of every month

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to output the 15th day of next month, based on input provided by the user.

For example:

> 04/02/2016 - input by user
>   05/15/2016 - output after calculation

This is my code, which I'm trying:

```
// this value is already coverted in strtotime.
$today = $loan_data['loan_applied_date'];
$numOfDays = date('t', $today);
$base = strtotime('+'.$numOfDays.' days', strtotime(date('m/01/Y', $today)));
$day15 = date('m/01/Y', $base);
$time = strtotime($day15);
```

By running the above code I am getting the 1st day. How can I get the 15th?

Example scenario:

> Suppose Subscription registered on 04/04/2016, so their next payment date will be 15th of next month or 05/15/2016.

Comment: I for one can't actually work out what you're trying to do...

Comment: @JonStirling  I am trying to setup a subscription payment, So no matter when they subscribe , The payment date will always be  15th of next month.

Comment: Get the month they subscribe. Then use just the month I.e 4. Add 1. Then make the date. Build it up as a string.

Comment: `echo date('15/d/Y', strtotime("next month", strtotime("2016-02-03")));`

Comment: @splash58 throws out this date 12/31/1969 with your suggested method

Comment: https://eval.in/552874 it's typo - '15/m/Y'

Comment: @splash58 thanks, i had to change the codes  a bit , but your advise helped me .

Answer (score 2):

Just use [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/datetime):

```
// Your description says that $loan_date['loan_applied_date'] is
// "already coverted in strtotime", so I assume a UNIX timestamp ...
DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $loan_date['loan_applied_date'])

    // When you import a UNIX timestamp into DateTime, it assumes UTC,
    // so we need to set your timezone back to whatever it is
    ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()))

    // Add 1 month
    ->modify('+1 month')

    // Hard-code the 15th day
    ->format('15/m/Y');
```

Comment: *WARNING* the `+1 month` thing is broken in PHP ! http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php#119082

Comment: @Sliq 31st of a month is an edge case. Since not every month has 31 days, there's room for multiple acceptable solutions and "+1 month" being translated into "+31 days" is one of them. It's not broken, just unexpected for some people.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple,using PHP you can take advantage of the flexible mktime function, as follows:

```
<?php

$today = strtotime("now");  //GRAB THE DATE - YOU WOULD WANT TO REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR VALUE

$year = date("Y", $today);  //GET MONTH AND YEAR VALUES
$month = date("m", $today);

$month++;                   //INCREMENT MONTH

echo date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 15, $year)); //OUTPUT WITH MKTIME

?>
```

Comment: mktime will handle that for you automatically. In the sense that it will wrap around and increment the year accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to recurring payments, this code charge payments every 15th:

```
//ini_set("date.timezone", "America/New_York"); //uncomment for test timezone
function getLastDay($date=false){
    return $date?date("t", strtotime($date)):date("t", strtotime(0));
}
function monthDayMatch($data = array('startDay'=>1,'day'=>1,'lastDayMonth','startMonth'=>1,'month'=>1,'frecuency'=>1)){
    if(($data['startMonth']%$data['frecuency'] == $data['month']%$data['frecuency']) && ($data['startDay'] == $data['day'] || $data['startDay'] > $data['lastDayMonth'])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$date = '04/02/2016';
$date = explode('/',$date);
$customer_date=array('month'=>$date[0],'day'=>$date[1],'year'=>$date[2],'all'=>implode('/',$date));  

$resp = monthDayMatch(array(
    'startMonth'=> $customer_date['month'], //initial customer month
    'month'     => date('m'),               //current month
    'frecuency' => 1,                       //recurring once a month
    'startDay'  => date('d'),               //current day day
    'day'       => 15,                      //day to validate
    'lastDayMonth'=>getLastDay($customer_date['all'])
));

//every 15th is true
if($resp){
    echo 'payment charge';
}else{
    echo 'no payment';
}
```